# Make program count up when given a negative number in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to make this code work in this way. When a negative number is give (-3) it should count up
-3, -2, -1, 0, Blastoff!
The code only counts down to 0 from a positive number and when a negative number is given, it only prints "Blastoff!"
 My initial thought was to change "<" to a ">" in the second function but didn't do anything.
 Also, I need to make it in such a way that when I enter 0, it would count up in pairs instead when number 0 is given, it breaks the program as a whole. 
Please help, **just remember you are talking to a newbie.**  
 This is a home practice exercise and I have tried to do it but cant figure it out, and haven't found anything in YouTube or here to explain the procedure in python.

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
def countdown(n):
    if n <= 0:
        print('Blastoff!')
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
countdown(n)

def countup(n):
    for n in range(0, -100000):
        if n >= 0:
            print ( "Blastoff! ")
        else:
            print (n)
            countup (n+1)
countup(n)

def countZero(n):
    if n == 0:
        print ("You hit the magic 0 ")
    else:
        print (n)
        countZero(n+2)
countZero()
```

Comment: It doen not make a difference. Already tried it. The for loop was the last thing I added. I will try again though, maybe I did something wrong before. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the for loop in countup, and make sure to pass in a negative number.

Note that the range method there is not doing what you expect:

```
>>> list(range(0, -3))
[]
```

If its negative you need to flip the start index. If you want zero to be shown then stop at 1:

```
>>> list(range(-3, 0))
[-3, -2, -1]

>>> list(range(-3, 1))
[-3, -2, -1, 0]
```

So you could do:

```
>>> def countup(n):
...     for n in range(n, 1):
...         if n >= 0:
...             print("Blastoff!")
...         else:
...             print(n)
...             
>>> countup(-3)
-3
-2
-1
Blastoff!
```

If you want to keep it recursive, then you don't need the loop at all:

```
>>> def countup(n):
...     if n >= 0:
...         print("Blastoff!")
...     else:
...         print(n)
...         countup(n + 1)
...         
>>> countup(-3)
-3
-2
-1
Blastoff!
```

**Bonus**
If you want one method to handle counting up and counting down, use another `if`/ `else` statement:

```
>>> def blastoff(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         print("Blastoff!")
...     else:
...         print(n)
...         if n > 0:
...             blastoff(n - 1)
...         else:
...             blastoff(n + 1)
... 
>>> blastoff(3)
3
2
1
Blastoff!
>>> blastoff(-3)
-3
-2
-1
Blastoff!
```

Comment: Im going to sleep on this to see the logic. What would happen if 0 is given?

Comment: In both methods you would just have blastoff printed. `list(range(0, 1)) == [0]`

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. You made it look so easy.

Comment: @EdyMolina A number of years of practice and a few grey hairs will do that! Keep practicing and you will go far, my friend!

Comment: Thanks so much for the bonus. Question, how would you go about to fix this. I want the code to count up in pairs when 0 is given but  now I realize that it is infinite because no number to end counting. So I need to input a 0 to initiate and a n to give it a cap. Will range work? I guess my question is, how do you tell the program start counting from 0 up and stop at n number. I went to bed thinking about it and I am still thinking about it. This is my 3rd week in programming by the way.

Comment: @EdyMolina Range sounds like an appropriate call. You can do `range(0, limit, 2)`. If the function can act in various ways depending on initial input, then I would break it up into smaller functions for each use-case (say `countdown`, `countup`, `count2`). You then can have a main function (maybe called `count`) whose only purpose is to pick one of those functions based on the initial input to forward the work to. This makes the code modular, and allows you to test the pieces individually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231529/discussion-between-edy-molina-and-flakes).